# Unable to install gnuplot

Tags: installation

I tried installing gnuplot using the command: `sudo apt-get install gnuplot` and I got the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package gnuplot
```

What to do?

Comment: `apt-cache search gnuplot` may give relevant information

Answer (score 2):

Open the Ubuntu Software Center and from the menu click *Edit* -> *Software Sources* -> *Ubuntu Software* (the first tab in the **Software Sources** window) and then check that the second entry in the list of software sources: *Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)* has a check mark in the checkbox on the left side of the entry. This will enable the universe repository, and you should be able to install gnuplot in any currently supported Ubuntu release (from Ubuntu 12.04 onward).

For Ubuntu 13.04 and later the instructions are the same except that the *Ubuntu Software* tab is accessed by selecting *Dash* -> *Software & Updates* -> *Ubuntu Software* tab.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Update the package list

```
sudo apt update
```

Step 2: Install `gnuplot`

```
sudo apt install gnuplot
```